# 3D Graph cut with shape prior

Tags: c++, graph, 3d, shapes

I'm applying 3D graph cuts based on Yuri Boykov's implementation in C++, itk and boost for min cut/max flow. First I provide some foreground and background seeds. Then I create the graph and assign the weight to the edges using 3D neighborhood (boundary term):

```
weight=vcl_exp(-vcl_pow(pixelDifference,2)/(2.0*sigma*sigma)),
```

being sigma a noise function.

Then I assign the source/sink edges depending on the intensity probability histogram (regional term):

```
   this->Graph->add_tweights(nodeIterator.Get(),
  -this->Lambda*log(sinkHistogramValue),
  -this->Lambda*log(sourceHistogramValue));
```

So the energy function is `E= regional term+boundary term`. Then, the cut is compute with Boycov's implementation, but I don't understand exactly how. Anyway, now I want to add a shape prior to the cut, but I have no clue on how to do it.

- Do I have to change the weight of the edges?
- Do I have to create another energy function? And if so, how?
- How could I provide both functions to the mincut/max flow algorithm?

Hope my questions are easily understandable.

Thank you very much,

Karen